# Does InBrowser have a separate clipboard it copies to by default?

Tags: copy-paste

I'm old and trying to learn how use an LG smartphone. InBrowser is telling me I'm copying to a clipboard. How do I see what I am copying? Do I actually have a clipboard?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. Never asked a question online before. So, I don't know if anybody is even out there. Please remember that I'm probably an idiot. So, be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used InBrowser, but most likely it is the same clipboard that every app uses, and it is probably not InBrowser telling you that either but the Android system or the phone itself. The "clipboard" is just a space/memory where the text you copy are temporarily saved. The contents disappear when you restart your phone. They also get replaced when you copy another set of text.

Anyway, you can install a third-party clipboard app like [aNdClip Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazing_create.android.andclipfree) (just search at [Google Play](https://play.google.com/) for more apps) to see what you copied. Or if you don't want to install anything, just open any app that has a textbox (like your Messaging/SMS app) and paste whatever you copied. You probably have to long-press on the text box, and a menu that says "Paste" will appear.